# How to create cascading dropdownLists in orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I'm trying to create a dependency between fields in orchard.
I need to create cascading dropdownList in Orchard.
e.g : Country and State (for each Country a couple of states must be displayed not all the content).
How can I do that with Orchard.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need make a choice from two options:

1. Create content type for Country and other content type for State (or may be one content type for Country and State). Then use Container and Containable part to create hierarchy (May be you should also use List module). Then override your field editor (you can use any field type, but i suggest you to use content picker field).
2. Use Taxonomy Module to create country-state hierarchy. Then use Taxonomy Field  and override editor for it.